# What is $(A∪C)-(B∩D)$, when $A=[3,8),B=[2,6],C=(1,4),D=(5,∞)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So the problem is asking for $(A∪C)-(B∩D)$, when $A=[3,8),B=[2,6],C=(1,4),D=(5,∞)$

My try at this:

$A∪C = (1,8)$

$B∩D = (5,6]$

$(1,8)-(5,6] = (1,5)∪(6,8)$

Would this be correct?

Edit: There's another one that I am unsure of.

$D-A = (8,∞)$
I am thinking that it should be $[8,∞)$ instead.

Comment: $(1,5]\cup (6,8)$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You are correct that $D - A = [8, \infty)$.

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks correct until you performed $(1, 8)-(5, 6]$. You did not include the $5$. However, $5$ is part of the first set and not part of the second, so we have to include it in our resultant set: $$(1, 5] \cup (6, 8)$$.

$D-A$ should be $[8, \infty)$ indeed, because $8$ is an element of $D$ and is not an element of $A$.